# My iOS app has been approved but not released yet. How do I release from team or another apple id?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My iOS app is currently in "Pending Developer Release" status. I've just realized I don't want to publish it to AppStore using my developer id.

Is it possible at this stage to create a team so my name is not listed in the app profile? Looking for a way of doing it without re-submitting the app for a review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change it without complete app resubmission. At this stage you can only change app description.

Comment: Could you recommend a way of creating a team profile? I've never done that before and it's confusing. I basically only need something to put instead of my First and Last name for the app release.

Comment: Go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and than edit any personal details you want :)

Comment: I've managed to just transfer it to another apple id right after publishing. Thanks!